# What SQL code do I need to read columns, regardless of format?

Tags: sql, ms-access, formatting

I'm trying to write an SQL code in Access to read data off a series of tables, which compares equivalent columns and writes them to a new table if the data differ between the tables.

Unfortunately, different tables often have the same information with different formatting (eg, one table has the relevant column left-justified, the other has it right-justified) and I've found that when I run the code, it reads these data as different.

Is there any way to read the data which is blind to formatting?

For clarity, my code currently looks like:

```
SELECT May.*
  FROM April
       Right JOIN May ON April.Info = May.Info
 WHERE April.Info IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have text values, I think you need to use the `TRIM()` function.

```
    SELECT May.*
      FROM April
Right JOIN May ON Trim(April.Info) = Trim(May.Info)
     WHERE April.Info IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. On closer inspection, the code doesn't actually seem to mind what format the columns are in, but it's probably a good idea to include TRIM anyway.